# Accessing the LineNumberTable from .class file

Tags: java, code-coverage, .class-file

```
LineNumber[] ln = new LineNumber[300];
LineNumberTable lnt = new LineNumberTable(LineNumberTable c);
ln = lnt.getLineNumberTable();
```

Query 1 : I don't know what I should be passing as parameter for the constructor of LineNumberTable.

Query 2: How do I access the LineNumberTable of a .class file or rather how do I link a .class file with the 'lnt' object?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using BCEL? Then sane thing would be to read its manual.

Comment: Why Reflection tools are not usefuls?